# Possible to bake boolean difference or use "exact" only when "fast" fails?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, fluid-simulation, baking

I am working with a 720 frame animation in Blender 2.91 with a liquid fluid simulation. To make the fluid simulation fit the container, I applied a boolean difference modifier on the fluid mesh.

Unfortunately, the "fast" boolean occasionally fails, resulting in the fluid mesh disappearing in 20+ frames during the animation. Using "exact" for the boolean difference results in no issues, but adds 30 minutes to the render time of each frame.

Is there a way to catch the failed "fast" boolean difference and retry with "exact"?

If not, might there be a way to bake each frame's boolean difference so I'm not having to recalculate it every time I adjust and rerender frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add both booleans, but disable the exact boolean. Then, you can keyframe their toggles on frame 0, by hovering over the buttons and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>. Then, you can go to the first frame, where you need exact boolean, toggle between the booleans, and again use <kbd>I</kbd> to keyframe them. Then on the first frame after that, where you no longer need exact, you can again toggle them and keyframe them, and so on.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never even considered keyframing multiple boolean operations. I'm continually amazed at how literally everything is keyframeable.